# Hot to define global middleware in nuxt-edge (Nuxt 2)

Tags: nuxt.js, nuxt-edge

middleware property on single page or layout works as expected.

But when I trying to defined middleware for every page using `nuxt.config.js` then middleware is not executed. Using

```
{
  router: { middleware: 'foo'} 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

middleware must be array

```
{
  router: { middleware: ['foo']} 
}
```